# Elasticsearch size before sort

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to do some kind of nested sort/size in elasticsearch? I'm trying to find all results for query (sorted by score, so best matches go first), limit the output to 200 results and then apply sorting/paging.

Example: user is searching for product. The search finds 10 000 matching products, but with different scores (we use very broad search so we always get lots of results). We take 200 best matching entries, apply user-defined sorting (e.g. user may want to sort results by category) and display as a list with 10 results/page.

So basically I need to do the following:

```
1. Perform search for product named "abc"
2. Sort results by score
3. Take first 200 results
4. Sort these 200 results by category
5. Take first 10 results to display them on first page
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [rescoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-rescore.html) will do exactly what you've described.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems that rescoring can't be used for sorting. I've found [an article](http://elasticsearchserverbook.com/elasticsearch-0-90-using-rescore/) which states: `Sometimes we want to show results, where the ordering of the first documents on the page is affected by the additional rules. Unfortunately this cannot be achieved by the rescore functionality. `

Comment: @emsi Yes, but you can rescore the results by category, which will give you the same result as sorting by category.